# AGM inequality for four variables

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove that for any $x,y,z,w \ge 0$
$$\sqrt[4]{xyzw} \le \frac{x+y+z+w}{4}$$

I tried using AGM and doing $xy \cdot zw = (\frac{xy + zw}{2})^2$ but couldn't get the proof

Comment: $x+y+z+w\ge2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw})$. Can you go on from here?

Comment: LHS is precisely the GM of 4 numbers and RHS is precisely the AM of 4 numbers, so AM-GM inequality directly gives you the proof. So if it is asked to "prove", is the question assuming that you don't use AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you explain how you got that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge0$ => $x+y-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\ge0$ => $\frac{x+y}{2}\ge\sqrt{xy}$ 
Using this, we get 
$x+y\ge2\sqrt{xy}$ and $z+w\ge2\sqrt{zw}$ 
Adding both, we get 
$x+y+z+w\ge2\sqrt{xy}+2\sqrt{zw}$ => $\frac{x+y+z+w}{2}\ge\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}$
Now using formula again on RHS, we get 
$\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}\ge2(xyzw)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ 
Combining last two equations, we get the required answer.

Comment: You might find the `\implies` command useful in the future. Also, framing math in `$$` as opposed to `$` makes it “display style.”

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{c+d}{2}}{2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}\cdot \frac{c+d}{2}}\geq \sqrt{\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{cd}}\geq \sqrt[4]{abcd}$$

Answer (score 1):

Lord Shark the Unknown's hint should get you there. If not, here's a different idea:

If one of the variables is zero, the inequality holds trivially (why?).

If all variables are positive, we have
$$\log (\sqrt[4]{xyzw}) = \frac{1}{4}\log (xyzw) =\frac{1}{4}(\log (x) + \log(y) + \log(z)+\log(w)) \\
\leq \log\left( \frac{1}{4}(x+y+z+w)\right)$$
Then, applying the exponential function to the first and to the last term, we arrive at the claim.